# Depending on screen size when page loads, show one modal or the other (Web & Mobile)

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

So for design purposes, I have created two different modals that will appear when the corresponding button is clicked, but each button only shows within certain screen sizes (using CSS @media query).

However, I now need to convert this so if the screen is 700px or more, it will display the modal when the page loads, or if the page is less than 700px, it will display the other modal, rather than a button being clicked.

```
<div class="discountweb">
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-modal-url="/_process/ajax_fetch_modal_content?type=snippet&name=Popup Discount Web">
 Discount Test Web
 </button>
</div>
<div class="discountmob">
 <button class="btn btn-default btn" data-modal-url="/_process/ajax_fetch_modal_content?type=snippet&name=Popup Discount Mobile">
 Discount Test Mobile
 </button>
</div>
<style>
 @media only screen and (min-width:700px) {
  .discountmob {
   display: none;
  }
 }
@media only screen and (max-width: 699px) {
 .discountmob {
  display: block;
 }
 .discountweb {
  display: none !important;
 }
}
</style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it by creating an event listener to check when the page loads, to calculate the size of the web page then click the corresponding button to activate the popup dependant on screen size.

```
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            var windowSize = $(window).width();
            if (windowSize >= 699) {
            document.getElementById('discountweb').click();
            } else if (windowSize <= 700) {
            document.getElementById('discountmob').click();
            }

        })
    </script>
    <div class="discountweb">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="discountweb" data-modal-url="/_process/ajax_fetch_modal_content?type=snippet&name=Popup Discount Web">
                    Discount Test Web
                </button>
    </div>
    <div class="discountmob">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn" id="discountmob" data-modal-url="/_process/ajax_fetch_modal_content?type=snippet&name=Popup Discount Mobile">
                    Discount Test Mobile
                </button>
    </div>
    <style>
            .discountmob {
                display: none;
            }

            .discountweb {
                display: none;
            }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit css file like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:700px) {
    .discountmob {
       display: none;
    }
   .discountweb {
       display: block;
   }
@media only screen and (max-width: 699px) {
   .discountmob {
       display: block;
   }
  .discountweb {
       display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had that originally but needed to automate it as its supposed to make a pop-up when a page is visited, rather than having someone click a button to make it appear. Figured it out in my answer below, thanks for the answer though!